# UILabel's gestureRecognizer with or without userInteractionEnabled

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I have been using gestureRecognizer to detect touch on a label without having userInteractionEnabled set along with so many other labels and views etc.

It has always worked until yesterday all of a sudden it won't recognize gestures then figured out with userInteractionEnabled, it'd start working.

I have no idea what's changed. Also I'm still using other gestured UI elements without setting userInteractionEnabled so it's very confusing..

Answer (score 0):

Acc to Aple Docs:-

**New label objects are configured to disregard user events and clip subviews by default. If you want to handle events in a custom subclass of UILabel, you must explicitly change the value of the userInteractionEnabled property to YES after initializing the object.**

For more information you can check this link.[UILabel](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILabel)

I think before yesterday you set userInteractionEnabled by your storyboard.And now by mistake you changed something (like changing the userInteraction of superview of label.You need to check this in your code)

Comment: I'm not using storyboard. All done programmatically.

Comment: By apple Documents If you are initialising the  UILabel You need to change the value of the userInteractionEnabled property to YES.

Comment: But seriously it used to work without having it set to YES... Or maybe I'm going crazy....